# iPhone 'slide to unlock' terminal command

Tags: iphone, terminal, command

Is it possible to 'slide to unlock' an iPhone using MobileTerminal? I have scoured google and cannot seem to find a command related to this. I simply mean that I would like to unlock the phone for use as if I had slid the 'slide to unlock' bar. My ultimate goal is to ssh over to the iPhone and execute this command remotely.

Comment: How do you SSH to iPhone?. Trying on a Jailbroken device?.

Comment: Yes, I am using a jailbroken device.